# How to store/download a Microsoft Access file in/from a server, with vba in another MS Access program

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, blob, ms-access-2016

I have a Microsoft Access Database connected to a SQL back-end.

At the moment the Access program checks it's version (saved as const variables) against the latest in a SQL table called Versions, and wont open unless it's the right version.
To update it my client has to go to all of the computers it's on and replace the file.

My idea is to have another Access file in the same directory called Updater, that would be opened up by the main file if it isn't the latest version. 
Updater would close the main program, download the latest version stored in the server, replace the outdated one, open up the main Access file, and close itself.

I can't work out how to actually store an Access .accde in a server however, and how to download it with vba.

Any help appreciated. And I'm open to doing it another way if there's a better one.

Comment: Because I don't have the time nor knowledge at the moment to do that. That's something for the future, and the reason I moved the back-end to SQL. It's all well and good talking about "why not just..." but we live in the real world, with real limitations.

Comment: We have a similar system for some internal UIs.  Users have a shortcut.  Shortcut points to a VBScript file, on a file share.  The script copies the current Access file to the local desktop and opens it.  we use the [file system object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (available in VBS/VBA) to copy.  You could use [ADO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/vbscript-ado-programming) to check against a variable table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script like that explained here:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23959/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-in-a-Citrix-environment.html)

It will transfer two copies, so you may have to reduce it slightly.